# "message": "Could not process payload" Postman

Tags: api, post, postman, aws-api-gateway

While trying to make a `POST` request on an endpoint using postman, the following error is shown

```
"message": "Could not process payload"
```

Due to `NDA`, I am not allowed to share the information about API or the JSON contents but below is the skeletal structure for the same

1. API

```
https://some.base.url/v0/resource/resource-id
```

2. JSON

The JSON contains nested data items such as lists, strings, etc.

Could someone help with its issue? Why exactly does this occur?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was related to improper formatting of the payload JSON. It may be due to unmatched `,` or `"` or due to any other relevant JSON formatting issue.